# "select new constructor" query returns java.lang.Object instead of instance of constructors class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, entitymanager

var `toShow` is instance of pure `java.lang.Object`, and the only way it works if I cast it to `FactionProjection`, and I do not think that's the proper way. My method:

```
    public FactionProjection getFactionById(int id){
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT new com.gamerecords.result_recorder.model.projection.FactionProjection(f.name)" +
        "FROM Faction f WHERE f.id = :id",FactionProjection.class)
        .setParameter("id",id);
    var toShow =  query.getSingleResult();
    return toShow;

}
```

constructor:

```
    public FactionProjection(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

what I have tried:

- changing second argument of `.createQuery` to `Faction.class`, or
  deleting it
- changing method `.getSingleResult()` to `.getResultList()`

Working code I have now is:

```
    public FactionProjection getFactionById(int id){
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT new com.gamerecords.result_recorder.model.projection.FactionProjection(f.name)" +
                " FROM Faction f WHERE f.id = :id",FactionProjection.class)
            .setParameter("id",id);
        var toShow =  (FactionProjection)query.getSingleResult();
        return toShow;
      }
```

I have seen many examples of "select new constructor" expression, and there was no need for casting, which makes me think I'm making a mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal Query API does not return the exact type of Object you expect and you need to cast. `Query#getSingleResult()` returns an `Object`. You can use `TypedQuery<T>` instead:

```
TypedQuery<FactionProjection> query;
var result= query.getSingleResult();
```